# How to configure hibernate 3.3 in Eclipse Galileo?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, orm, galileo

I am working on Galileo but I am not able to find the plugin for hibernate 3.3 . Can anybody send me the plugin link please? And also send me the spring 2.x latest version plugin also.

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate Tools for Eclipse](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html) is a component of [JBoss Tools](http://jboss.org/tools) and you'll find the update site at [this location](http://jboss.org/tools/download.html).

For  [Spring IDE](http://springide.org/), you can a recent milestone compatible with Eclipse 3.5 from this [update site](http://www.springsource.com/milestone/e3.4) (the link is correct and working with the update manager).

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Tools for Eclipse is a component of JBoss Tools and you'll find the update site at this location.

For Spring IDE, you can a recent milestone compatible with Eclipse 3.5 from this update site (the link is correct and working with the update manager)